# How difficult would it be to interact with a Facebook poker game?

Tags: facebook

There is an online facebook poker game. This game is constantly sending and receiving information to the player's browser about all the things going on in the game. How hard would it be for a good programmer to make a program that could interface with the game server so that the user wouldn't have to use their web browser to play the game?

Comment: What's wrong with this question?

Comment: It poses no specific programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd put it in the 'medium' challenge bin offhand, but the specifics of the game could make it a lot harder or a lot easier.

If the game isn't sending the data encrypted it could get harder, if the game is using Flash or Silverlight with TCP sockets or some specific protocol (like flash remoting), then you'll limit your technology choices (or make it harder), which in turn limits your pool of "good" developers.

Likewise, there may be some challenges to managing the FB session in a way that mimics the browser, you might have to do user-agent spoofing... Lots of things to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Moderately. They probably use remote procedure call, or other communication form, which is native to the chosen platform (Flash?). If it is HTML5 (probably JSON structures) then it is pretty easy to implement it in other languages. If it is flash then you need some middleware which implements flash's communication protocols for your chosen desktop language.